# batch comparing files sharing a prefix with htmldiff

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

I have a bunch of files named like this:

```
something08-a-v1.html
something08-b-v2.html
something09-a-v1.html
something09-b-v2.html
somethingelse10-a-v1.html
somethingelse10-b-v2.html
```

`-a-` is a previous version of the file. `-b-` is a newer version. So I have two files to compare each time.

I would like to compare them with [htmldiff](https://github.com/cygri/htmldiff).

`htmldiff -a something08-a-something.html something08-b-something.html -o something08-diff.html`

How can i automate this?

I think the more obvious way is to use `find` but I have some hard time to manage patterns for select only two files and rename without `-[/b]a-v[1/2]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have the file name patterns, you know one is `-a-` and the other is `-b-`, and assuming that you only ever have pairs of files as you show, you can use that:

```
$ for file in *-a-*; do 
    prefix=${file%%-*}
    htmldiff -a "$prefix"-a-* -b "$prefix"-b-* -o "$prefix"-diff.html
 done
```

The `${var%%pattern}` syntax will remove the longest match of `pattern` from the end of the variable's value. Here, the pattern is `-*` so it will remove everything from the first `-` to the end, leaving you with your prefix.

Note that according to the [GitHub page](https://github.com/cygri/htmldiff) of `htmldiff`, there is no `-b` option and the `-a` option is:

> -a --accurate-mode Use accurate mode instead of risky mode

So I suspect the command you *actually* want is:

```
$ for file in *-a-*; do 
    prefix=${file%%-*}
    htmldiff -a "$prefix"-a-* "$prefix"-b-* -o "$prefix"-diff.html
 done
```

Or:

```
$ for file in *-a-*; do 
    prefix=${file%%-*}
    htmldiff "$prefix"-a-* "$prefix"-b-* -o "$prefix"-diff.html
 done
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work presuming you only have two files with each prefix on the filename:

```
htmldiff prefix-*.html -o prefix-diff.html
```

Comment: In fact, I am trying to automate the prefix detection because I have a lots of files. I am looking for a way to compare each html file which share a prefix (without indicate it) and output the result in a new file name prefix-diff.html